# Pull a line to ground if a HIGH signal (3.3V) is on the line

Tags: gpio

I have a X-Wing model ([by DeAgostini](https://www.deagostini.com/de/sammlungen/star-wars-bau-deinen-x-wing/)) and I would like to include some sounds from an Adafruit SoundFX Board using the [simple trigger setup](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-audio-fx-sound-board/triggering-audio).

The Adafruit Board would trigger a sound T00.WAV - T09.wav when a line connected to this very GPIO pin 0-9 is set to ground.

The X-Wing electronic however only gives me some 3.3 HIGH lines - I hijacked a Line from the Lasers, from the Engines and the line powering the light pf R2D2.

I'm thinking of a setup like this:

```
   X-Wing circuit    Magic Box  Adafruit SoundFX Board
          emits       +---+              expects
   LASER  3.3 V     ->|   |->   GPIO_00  GND
   ENGINE 3.3 V     ->|   |->   GPIO_01  GND
   R2D2   3.3 V     ->|   |->   GPIO_02  GND
                      +---+
```

As you can see I'm looking for this magic box - something that converts a 3.3 V input signal in such a way, that it pulls the line on the other side to GND.

Comment: Have you given any thought what you could use? So we don't suggest the same things. Like transistors.

Comment: How about 74HCT01?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have pointed out that I am a complete new to the topic of electronics. I am a software engineer by heart, so I'm still learning the microcontroller and electronic parts as I'm progressing with building my X-Wing.

Comment: @winny Hi and thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I seem to be unable to find the SN74HCT01 but can only find SN74HCT00 - As I said, I am a complete  noob, so forgive if this is a stupid question, but are these two interchangeable? So could I also use th SN74HCT00 https://www.amazon.de/-/en/POPESQ®-74HCT00-socket-DIP14-A3702/dp/B08R2YQ63R/ref=sr_1_30?dchild=1&keywords=74HCT01&qid=1629126817&sr=8-30

Comment: Dang it. I mistyped. 74hct04 is the one you want. Widely available. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/base-product/texas-instruments/296/74HCT04/1310

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is a *logic inverter*. It's one of the standard gates, so there's thousands of dedicated inverting logic ICs you can buy, and millions of ways of constructing your own logic inverter. This should be a really nice mini-project to research yourself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the  direction of logic inverters. I have one follow up question on this, however. The circuits in question, that is the on-board X-Wing circuit and the sound circuit do not share a common ground or power source. That is because the on-board X-Wing circuit comes from DeAgostini whereas the sound circuitt is an addition from myself. Hence the question: Do I need to take any extra things or components into account when the circuit that issues the 3,3v signal is separate from the circuit that's line is being pulled to low?

Comment: @siliconchris Is there a problem with connecting grounds of the two systems?

Comment: @RonBeyer: That is exactly where I reach the limits of my knowledge of electronics. There are two circuits, each has it's own battery pack - CAN I share a common ground here, or is this going to blow something up??? And, suppose I could have both circuits share a ground, how am I going to do that? A cable between both GND lines of the battery boxes?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You can tie both grounds together at the battery (as long as you don't tie the +'s together). Now you have a shared ground reference, it won't blow anything up.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do that then.